# Set value of column based on another column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, sql-update, boolean

I'm working with Postgres 9.1 and I have added a new boolean column to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE frontend_item ADD COLUMN is_generic BOOLEAN;
```

The value of this column will be based on the value of another column, `code`. If characters 10-11 of `code` are `AA` then the value of `is_generic` should be `TRUE`. Otherwise it should be false (or null if it hasn't been set yet).

My question, is how can I do this in Postgres? I've been able to work out some individual components using the docs:

```
 UPDATE frontend_item SET is_generic...
```

And then I know I can get the substring of `code` as follows:

```
 substring(code from 10 for 2)
```

But how do I turn substring into a boolean, and then glue it together with the `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE frontend_item
SET    is_generic = (substring(code from 10 for 2) = 'AA');
```

But do you really need the redundant column? You can just keep using the expression `substring(code from 10 for 2)`, which is more reliable in the face of possible updates to the table. The cost for the function is low and keeping the table small is a benefit for overall performance.

Redundant storage is rarely a good idea. Only for special optimizations.

BTW, there is a less verbose Postgres variant doing the same:

```
substr(code, 10, 2)
```

[See string functions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I want to index on this value, which is why I was thinking of creating a redundant column. But could I do something like `CREATE INDEX code_substr ON code (substring(code from 10 for 2) = 'AA')`? And then query it using `SELECT * FROM CODE where (substring(code from 10 for 2) = 'AA');`? This feels a bit prone to typos at query time, though.

Comment: @Richard: You *could*. Postgres has expression indexes. There are many example here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgres]+url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.postgresql.org%2Fdocs%2Fcurrent%2Finteractive%2Findexes-expressional.html But an index on a boolean column (or expression) is hardly ever useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025094/performance-tuning-create-index-for-boolean-column/12026593#12026593. Start a new question about that if its unclear. You can always link to this one for context.